# Cannot auto mount a CIFS device

Tags: mount, automount

I am trying to mount a USB device (acting like a NAS) onto my Ubuntu (20.04) server.
Running the below works fine via ssh `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/"Music (at BackupNAS)"/CD /media/asusHDD -o rw,credentials=/Downloads/.ASUS-HDD-credentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0`

However I want to have the mount done automatically but NONE of the following works despite extensive search on the web:

1. /etc/fstab entry as
   `//192.168.1.1/"Music (at BackupNAS)"/CD /media/asusHDD cifs rw,credentials=/Downloads/.ASUS-HDD-credentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0 0 0`
2. Creating 2 systemd services as media-asusHDD.automount and media-asusHDD.mount
3. Creating a shellscript and running it as a systemd service
4. Creating a shellscript  and executing via a music player custom script.

Any guidance will be much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Try with octal rather than quoting for the whitespace: `//192.168.1.1/Music\040(at\040BackupNAS)/CD`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. Tried it via a systemd service call and still the same error

Comment: Error is Oct 03 04:29:14 hpenvy systemd[1424]: mountHDD.service: Failed to execute /Downloads/mountHDD.sh: Exec format error
Oct 03 04:29:14 hpenvy systemd[1424]: mountHDD.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /Downloads/mountHDD.sh: Exec format error
Oct 03 04:29:14 hpenvy systemd[1]: mountHDD.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 03 04:29:14 hpenvy systemd[1]: mountHDD.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: Just to be sure, I changed the USB device server (NAS like) smb.conf file removing the spaces. I can mount via ssh but still does not work as a shell script. Command that works  via ssh: `mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/MusicatBackupNAS/CD /media/asusHDD -o rw,credentials=/Downloads/.ASUS-HDD-credentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0`

Answer (score 0):

I updated my USB/NAS server config so that no space is needed.
I can mount using ssh via:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/music/CD /media/asusHDD -o rw,credentials=/Downloads/.ASUS-HDD-credentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0
```

But can't run this as a systemd service or in fstab..... anyone has idea what i can try. Thanks